# Is it possible to assign each vlan to a physical port on the ZyXEL USG40?

Tags: vlan, lan

I'm trying to configure a ZyXEL USG40 to act as a switch that can physically separate 3 vlans from each other. I was told this product would be sufficient to setup a company network with 3 separate vlans. However, after helping me configure the vlans, they told me I'd need an additional switch that allows me to bind each vlan to one or more physical ports.

I was wondering whether it would be possible to assign each physical port on the ZyXEL USG40 to a vlan, so that:

- LAN1 (P2) >> 10.0.200.1 (vlan2)
- LAN2 (P3) >> 10.0.300.1 (vlan3)
- DMZ (P4) >> 10.0.400.1 (vlan4)

The WAN port would be connected directly to the modem. Under each vlan we plan to add a switch for VoIP (on .200), a switch with local workstations and servers (on .300) and a guest wireless AP (on .400).

The web interface seemingly allows for something like this, by assigning each ethernet interface to its own zone, and then adding a vlan on that zone and base port. However, that doesn't seem to work. Granted, I'm very new to all of this and I don't really know whether I'm doing this correctly.

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible, but unless you want only one device connected to each port you'll obviously need one or more switches connected to lan1, lan2, dmz.  Provide more info about what "doesn't work" and I'll try to help.  I have a couple USG200s on my network.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you assing a separate, physical switch to each of your network zones VLANs are useless; just assign a zone to your interface and let Zywall take care for routing and firewall rules.
Obviously you cannot mix different end points on same device (ex, pcs and voip phones on the same switch).